# After restarting Chromium, fonts are malformed

Tags: arch-linux, kde, fonts, chrome

Everything works great until I restart Chromium. Then the fonts appear as in the screenshot. The weird part is that only the tab title and the link is malformed. And it won't fix till a system restart. Arch Linux, fully updated, with KDE.

[image]

Comment: No screenshot. Probably also need the complete markup or a link to debug, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Also, how do you restart Chromium exactly?

Comment: Sorry about that...screenshot added. I restart it normally. Close i for a while and reopen it later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely a [bug with pixman](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/32612). It has also been [filed upstream](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160505).

There are [several](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=152753) [threads](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=153148) on the Arch boards about this issue, with various suggested workrounds—depending on your driver.