# Fonts in chromium

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, chrome

(no, it isn't [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57377/after-restarting-chromium-fonts-are-malformed)) My bold fonts are completely deformed in some sites (mostly SE) in chromium. I have had this issue for a while on two Arch systems, but not in Ubuntu. Here is an example from a [question I was viewing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/61309/radio-button-yes-no-or-no-yes) (getting carried away again ...):

[image]

As you can see, some letters are bigger than others, and it generally looks a mess. I tried messing with the chromium fonts, but it seems the problematic SE sites have their own fonts they want, which overrides chromium's settings.

What is going wrong? Is this some kind of extreme hinting that totally malforms the letters? Or is there something I ought to install?

Come to think of it, what font is it? The only fitting fonts I have installed are Helvatica (Neue) and Nimbus Sans.

Comment: I have had this problem take a look here http://kaslnetwork.com/articles/making-ugly-fonts-pretty-in-arch-linux/

Comment: @vfbsilva This is .. weird .. but I can't seem to be able to select the text for the fix. This might take a bit.

Comment: @vfbsilva Printed to pdf, copied from there .... and IT WORKS! Wow! Why don't you repeat that as an answer, then I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: added as formal answer, please add more details to the question.

Comment: @vfbsilva I don't see what there is to add. The screenshot shows the (ex-)problem rather well, in my opinion. Anyway, +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `~/fontconfig/fonts.conf` file containing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
  <fontconfig>
  <match target="font" >
    <edit mode="assign" name="rgba" >
      <const>rgb</const>
    </edit>
  </match>
  <match target="font" >
    <edit mode="assign" name="hinting" >
      <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
  </match>
  <match target="font" >
    <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle" >
      <const>hintslight</const>
    </edit>
  </match>
  <match target="font" >
    <edit mode="assign" name="antialias" >
      <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
  </match>
  <match target="font">
    <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
      <const>lcddefault</const>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Then logout/login.

The above only effects a single user, for all usersplace the xml config inside `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/29-prettify.conf` and symlink it:

```
ln -s /etc/fonts/conf.avail/29-prettify.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/29-prettify.conf
```

(or while in `/etc/fonts/conf.d` directory: `ln -s ../conf.avail/29-prettify.conf` ).

**For Debian:** Watch that XDG_CONFIG_HOME doesn't change in the future, currently it's default is `~/.config`.

Comment: Debian XFCE possible solution, different settings for the file https://www.internalpointers.com/post/fixing-ugly-fonts-chrome-chromium-debian-xfce